# Connect to different Hubs on different pages

Tags: signalr

I am building a single page app which uses sammy.js, knockout.js and SignalR. The main page (index.html) loads additional html pages into a div based upon the client side route.

I have 2 SignalR hubs, one is connected to by the initial page for server side push data and this works fine. However one of the pages which are loaded when the user navigates to it should also connect to a different hub.

In the main page I am doing the following:

```
window.hubReady = $.connection.hub.start()

var hub1 = $.connection.hub1;
hub1.updateReceived = function () { 
    alert('data from server');
}

window.hubReady.done(function() {
    hub1.server.start(); 
});
```

In the second page I have:

```
var hub2 = $.connection.hub2;
hub2.updateReceived = function () { 
    alert('data from server');
}

window.hubReady.done(function() {
    hub2.server.start(); 
});
```

However I never receive any updates in the second page.

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to receive updates from a hub you must have at least 1 client side function declared for that hub when the connection is started.  Judging from the libraries you are using I'm assuming you have a single page application and therefore don't instantiate your hub2 data until the connection has already started.

So an easy fix would be to just declare a hub2 client side function alongside your hub1 client side function before start is called.  If you want to add more client side functions after the connection has started you'll have to use the .on method.

AKA:

```
hub2.on("updateReceived", function () {
    alert("data from server");
});
```

Comment: Really? that's annoying, I was hoping to keep the client side code separated into the view model for the view it's concerned with. Also, will that mean that the server will be sending data to the client which I will just be discarding if the hub2 view isn't loaded?

Comment: In your case yes.  Another alternative if you truly want to prevent the extra data is you can re-start the SignalR connection.  Aka when you navigate to one of your inner pages that requires the hub2 you can call stop and then add new hub2 methods and then call connection start.  At that point you could also remove bindings from hub1.

Comment: hub1 stays alive as long as the app is running, hub2 is only used by one view while it's open. Ok so if I do the stop/add/start, will I need to remove hub2 when the app navigates away from that view? will the hub connection be kept in scope and still receive data even though there is no view to render it in?

Comment: Yes if you no longer want to receive data for the hub you will have to remove the handlers when you navigate away

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: Simple as calling delete hub2.updateReceived or doing hub2.off('updateReceived') depending on how you bound it

Comment: OK thanks, I'll see if that works with how I'm trying/wanting to use it.

Comment: This worked the best, although I still have to work out how my sub view knows when it's being navigated away from to drop the connection to hub2.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a lib called SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.
it proxies between server side domain events and client side code. Its designed with MVVM and SPA in mind and takes care of all the hub plumbing. Check the wiki for how to set it up.

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki

once its configured all you need to subscribe to a event is

```
ViewModel = function() {
   signalR.eventAggregator.subscribe(MyApp.Events.TestEvent, this.onTestEvent, this);
};
```

MyApp.Events.TestEvent corresponds to a server side .NET event. You can also constraint which event should go to which usera